# Does Facebook host shared/liked images pointed to with og:image?

Tags: facebook

Just curious if Facebook hosts a copy or if they will be linking to my server, in which case the shared image URL might be hit many hundreds of times.

Comment: You could’ve found the answer to that question yourself, if you had just looked at some of the images sources with Firebug …

Comment: Didn't want to log into Facebook at work.

Answer (score 0):

They use the copy. Once the image is retrieved - it will be served from their CDN

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @Doug Treadwell: I've seen it somewhere but cannot find now :-(